# Hot to get Gradle running with elastic bamboo agent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bamboo, amazon-ebs

I am struggling a little bit to get Gradle running with Elastic Bamboo. I would install Gradle on our mounted EBS-Snapshot. Then take a new one and afterwards add this as Executable capability to the elastic image config. Is this enough? Since normally (like this guide: http://exponential.io/blog/2015/03/30/install-gradle-on-ubuntu-linux/) you would also manipulate your profile - but this is located on the ephemeral EBS of the image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script (e.g. for Gradle 2.5):

```
mkdir -p ~/mnt/bamboo-ebs/gradle && cd $_

wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-bin.zip

unzip gradle-2.5-bin.zip
```

Then take a new snapshot from the EBS volume and use this in your elastic agent.

Afterwards add "Executable Capability" to your image configuration with this as path:

*/mnt/bamboo-ebs/gradle/bin/gradle*

Now you can use Gradle as Command in Build plans and add the task name as argument - e.g. "build".